# How to perform this algebraic step in the derivation of the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

In deriving the variance of the uniform distribution I need to complete the following step.

$\frac{b^3-a^3}{3(b-a)}=\frac{a^2+a b+b^2}{3}$

Unfortunately it is not clear to me how this step is performed.

The following things would help me out:

- Additional steps between the equation
- Advice on how I could have seen this myself in the firstplace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think you were talking about this step in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nvfd.jpg)

*Hopefully this helps you Tim.*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Welcome Tim  , this is my first help to the community